# Why subprocess stdout to a file is written out of order?

Tags: python, subprocess, redirect

I have a python script that calls an executable. The executable's output is redirected to a log file along with some info about the time it was called. For example, using `python -V` as the executable to illustrate:

```
import time, subprocess
with open('./LOGFILE.txt', 'a') as F:
    F.write('******\n')
    F.write('Events on %s :\n'%time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime()))
    EXE_output = subprocess.call(['python', '-V'], stdout=F, stderr=F)
```

The output of the file `LOGFILE.txt` is:

```
Python 2.7.3
******
Events on 2013-04-10 19:27:25 :
```

Where I was expecting it as follows:

```
******
Events on 2013-04-10 19:27:25 :
Python 2.7.3
```

I wrote the `******` and time info in the opened log file before running the subprocess and redirecting its output and error into the file. Why is ordering like that? and how can I reorder?

Comment: Try F.flush(), before running the subprocess.

Comment: Worked! Can you post it as an answer with a little explanation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should call F.flush() before running the subprocess. The reason for this is that the subprocess will flush the buffers when it finishes, whereas you are not.

Comment: So I was writing in the right order, but actually the subprocess process was getting its data to the disk before me?

Comment: Technically no, the data was flushed out of the user space buffers, which are process specific. The kernel ones aren't. When the process finishes, it flushes its buffers, so if you want the data to be sure to arrive to disk (eventually) in the same order, you need to flush.

Comment: Moving data from a process to the operating system is an expensive operation so the C libraries buffer data in the process and write less frequently. When your subprocess exited, its clib flushed the data to the operating system, but your parent process was still holding its data locally. From the operating system's point of view, the subprocess wrote first.