# How send STDOUT to a file and STDOUT+STDERR to another file in a bash script?

Tags: bash, redirect, stdout, stderr

I want write a bash shell script that redirect STDOUT to file "result.log", STDERR+STDOUT to file "complete.log. 
Best will be a third file with only STDERR suc as "error.log. 
Finally show STDOUT to terminal

Linux mint 19.1

```
#!/bin/bash
exec  > >(tee -a result.log full.log) 
exec 2>>full.log 
echo "This is stdout" 
echo "This is stderr" >&2 
echo "This is stdout 2" 
echo "This is stderr 2" >&2 
echo "This is stdout 3" 
echo "This is stderr 3" >&2 
echo "This is stdout 4" 
echo "This is stderr 4" >&2
```

output

```
full.log:This is stderr 
full.log:This is stderr 2
full.log:This is stderr 3 
full.log:This is stderr 4
full.log:This is stdout
full.log:This is stdout 2
full.log:This is stdout 3
full.log:This is stdout 4
result.log:This is stdout
result.log:This is stdout 2
result.log:This is stdout 3
result.log:This is stdout 4
```

Expected

```
full.log:This is stdout
full.log:This is stderr
full.log:This is stdout 2
full.log:This is stderr 2
full.log:This is stdout 3
full.log:This is stderr 3
full.log:This is stdout 4
full.log:This is stderr 4
result.log:This is stdout
result.log:This is stdout 2
result.log:This is stdout 3
result.log:This is stdout 4
```

Comment: I think you're experiencing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868312/correcting-out-of-order-printing-from-stream-redirection

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
exec 1> >(tee -a result.log >>full.log)
exec 2>>full.log
```

But consider, that the output ordering in `full.log` is now:

```
This is stderr
This is stderr 2
This is stderr 3
This is stderr 4
This is stdout
This is stdout 2
This is stdout 3
This is stdout 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works only if bash supports `/dev/fd/NUM`. It keeps the output in order.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 1>>result.log 2>>full.log

echo "This is stdout"   | tee -a /dev/fd/2
echo "This is stderr"   >&2 
echo "This is stdout 2" | tee -a /dev/fd/2
echo "This is stderr 2" >&2 
echo "This is stdout 3" | tee -a /dev/fd/2
echo "This is stderr 3" >&2 
echo "This is stdout 4" | tee -a /dev/fd/2
echo "This is stderr 4" >&2
```