# ADO pipelines redirect buffer making pytest output out of order

Tags: azure, logging, pytest, pipeline, tox

I am running tests in ADO pipelines.
The problem is the output (stderr and stdout) from the ADO pipeline tests is out of order.
My pipeline runs a script that calls tox which runs pytest which runs my tests.

Following troubleshooting I tried:

- I dont have control over the code base so I cant flush every output.
- I am not calling python directly with my tests, I am using pytest, so I cant use `-u`
- I already tried using `pytest -s`, this does not help, logs are still out of order.
- I tried tee'ing all output `2&1>` to a log file and creating an artifact, but the same thing happens in ADO pipelines.

Note: none of this happens when I run my code locally, I see the order it should be in.

The following links I have already reviewed but I cant seem to find a solution with them:

- Why redirect output shows out of order: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868312/correcting-out-of-order-printing-from-stream-redirection)
- issue created for the problem I am having: [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/106)

how can I fix the order of ADO pipeline output of my tests with the current limitations I have?